# JS Array cannot read property 663 of undefined with a calculation as an index

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

Here's my current code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deadsource/r4577/)

At line 36: `tempX = x + k - seedSeparation / 2;` gives an error. If I change `tempX` to `x`, `k` or `seedSeparation / 2` it works.

Code excerpt:

```
var mapX = 1000,
mapY = mapX,
seedLess = 3,
seedSeparation = 32, //Even number
canSeed, tempX, tempY,
x, y, seedNum = Math.round(((mapX + mapY) / 2) / seedLess);

var map = [];

for (i = 0; i <= mapX; i++){
    map[i] = [];
    for (k = 0; k <= mapY; k++){
        map[i][k] = 0;
    }
}
x = Math.floor((Math.random()*mapX)+1);
y = Math.floor((Math.random()*mapY)+1);
for (l = 0; l <= seedSeparation; l++){
    for (k = 0; k <= seedSeparation; k++){
        tempX = x + k - seedSeparation / 2; //Here lies the problem
        tempY = y + l - seedSeparation / 2;
        if(tempX >= 0 || tempY >= 0){
            if(map[tempX][tempY]){
                canSeed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's the problem here? Why does this calculation gives me an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the fiddle, the problem isn't on the line you've marked, but rather a couple of lines further down:

```
if(map[tempX][tempY]){
```

It means that there was no entry in `map` for the value in `tempX`, and therefore `map[tempX]` is giving you the value `undefined`. Then you try to do (in effect) `undefined[tempY]`, which fails because you can't read a property value from `undefined`.

You can rewrite it to guard against that possibility:

```
if(map[tempX] && map[tempX][tempY]){
```